# Walking tours in Seoul

Tags: tours, walking, seoul

I'm having a 14 hour overnight stopover in Seoul in early December.  I was looking to leave the airport and maybe see some of Seoul.  Are there any reputable and good night tours of Seoul, especially walking tours?

Comment: Seoul is really big and confusing but there is a lot of stuff to see so a walking tour would be a very good option for a short stop like yours so hopefully we'll get some good answers.

Comment: @hippietrail: +1. Hence the bounty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take the [Seoul City Night Tour](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/SI/SI_EN_3_4_4_2.jsp). This is a non expensive city tour that departs at 8pm all days except mondays and city holidays. The problem is that you won't see all main city sightseeing, but it will give you an idea of the city.

If you are looking for something more interesting (and expensive) a friend was very happy with the night tour of [I love Seoul](http://iloveseoultour.com/City-Tours-Night). I've not tried, but it seems more complete. It starts at 5pm (I don't know if that's a problem for you) and must be 2 people to take part in the tour.

Answer (score 0):

Seoul is super active at night. So you can pretty much do everything you would be able to do in the day until late at night. One of my favorites was the [Meyong-dong street food at night](https://ollieandthecaptain.com/fun-things-to-do-in-seoul/#13_Treat_Yourself_To_Myeongdong_Street_Food) There are also some really cool [theme cafes](https://ollieandthecaptain.com/fun-things-to-do-in-seoul/#10_Pop_In_At_Themed_Cafes) around there too!